# start a spring boot application from test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I have two spring boot applications. The first one manages data in a PostgreSQL database. The other one exposes this data over REST.

In my first spring boot application I write a test that uses a test database. Now I want to write a test for the other application (REST), that test needs data inside the database.

How can I use the first spring boot application in my test for the second spring boot application?

Or can I setup that the test only can be run if the test from the first spring boot application?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

First of all: you shouldn't start neither the first nor the second application in your tests. It will slower down your testing drastically. What's more you will be dependent on another application that in reality may be developed by another team - bad idea.

In fact, you've got something like 3 ways to do it:

1. Use Wiremock or some other dummy stub service- this approach will suite you if you're ready no to call the "real" application. The service should mimic your application (should expose the same interface i.e. url, HTTP method, the same response)
2. Use both the application in Docker containers and start it with Docker Compose - you can use here either a real database deployed somewhere or another container with predefined data
3. Deploy the first service somewhere along with the database and run either integration tests or system or end-to-end tests

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**: I meant you shouldn't start apps **in tests**. Also, to my mind it is obvious enough that we're talking about integrating testing at least as the guy mentions testing of whole request trip starting with the REST app. Maybe that clarifies the things to downvoters

Comment: If you're not going to start the applications, how do you do integration testing?

Comment: @EngineerDollery you can use lightweight HTTP clients in your code to call another service. Not sure I understand you point) ideally, you should have you apps deployed somewhere e.g. in a cloud

Comment: You said, "you shouldn't start neither the first nor the second application in your tests". I said, nonsense, you have no choice but to test against the real components at some point during your tests. I think you're confusing unit, component, and integration testing. The OP is clearly asking about integration testing.

Comment: @Engineer Dollery No it is not. Ideally, you should have an environment with all the application used. E.g. if my team is working on application A, another one - on application B. A calls B, B calls db. I f I want not to depend on service B there should be an environment with both db and service B deployed. This way you can call service B in your test doing integration testing this way. Hope now it is clear. If you start B every time in your tests yourself - you're in a trouble as if they break something in another team you will have to carry their work first having a look at B

Comment: OK If I have understand it right: for my Junit Test in my REST application I feed the test database with dummy values (directly in JUnit). If I want to test both application together I implement a integration test. Is that right?

Comment: @Burny not exactly. For your REST app in a unit test you mock the app calling db. And yes, the part about testing apps together is right. But actually you can do it with JUnit as well, calling a real service from test

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of testing. The first is unit testing -- this confirms that your business logic works. The second form is integration testing, which is again split into two parts -- the first you test the component in isolation to confirm that it communicates the way you expect (sometimes called component testing), and the second you test the component against other, real, components.

You can easily do unit-tests in maven/spring-boot, and it's fairly easy to do component testing too. The integration testing however is usually a lot more complicated and usually needs to involve a mechanism outside the simple maven build system. The most common approach to this is to use a CI/CD tool, like Jenkins or CircleCI.

The usual pattern is to run the unit-tests first because they are the fastest, then component tests, then integration tests. The latter often requires an 'environment' to be created that contains all of the collaborating components that compose a service (the two spring-boot apps in your case).

For integration testing, we often find that the biggest problem is "Configuration Management", which is basically a description of which versions of which components work together. For your problem you need a database, data, and two spring-boot apps, along with their configuration and environment data.